# Textwrap a string value that is in a list within a dictionary during display

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary like the below but I have trouble trying to textwrap the below:

```
dict= { 'ProductA' : ['2020-08-03 16:26:21', 'This painting was done by XNB.The artist seeks to portray  the tragedies caused by event XYZ. The painting weighs 2kg.'], 'ProductB':['2020-08-03 16:26:21','This painting is done by ONN.This painting is done by ONN.Decades later, it was discovered in the black market of country XYZ.It was bought for 2 million dollars by ABC.']}
```

Desired Outcome for display of dictionary:

```
  Product Name      Last Edited               Information
  Product A         2020-08-03 16:26:21       This painting was done by XNB.The artist 
                                              seeks to portray  the tragedies caused by
                                              event XYZ. The painting weighs 2kg.

  Product B         2020-08-03 16:26:21       This painting is done by ONN.This painting
                                              is done by ONN.Decades later, it was 
                                              discovered in the black market of country
                                              XYZ.It was bought for 2 million dollars 
                                              by ABC.
```

Below is my attempt to output the display as above:

```
from textwrap import wrap

    print("{:<25} {:<30} {:<10}".format('Product Name','Last Edited','Information'))
for product_name, data in dict.items():
    last_edit, info = data
    wrapped_info=wrap(info, 45)
    
    print("{:<25} {:<30} {:<10}".format(product_name, last_edit, wrapped_info))
```

#TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.   format

I don't quite understand what the error is trying to say. Where did I go wrong and how should I code it to get the desired output?

Comment: `plant_name, revision_time`??? please fix up your question!

Comment: Hi goodvibration, thanks for pointing out the typo. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your code is `wrap()` return a list of strings. you need to convert the result of `wrap()` to string using `join()`.

Try this:

```
from textwrap import wrap

d = { 'ProductA' : ['2020-08-03 16:26:21', 'This painting was done by XNB.The artist seeks to portray  the tragedies caused by event XYZ. The painting weighs 2kg.'], 'ProductB':['2020-08-03 16:26:21','This painting is done by ONN.This painting is done by ONN.Decades later, it was discovered in the black market of country XYZ.It was bought for 2 million dollars by ABC.']}

print("{:<25} {:<30} {:<10}".format('Product Name','Last Edited','Information'))
for product, data in d.items():
    date, info = data
    wrapped_info = f'\n{" " * (25 + 30 + 2)}'.join(wrap(info, 45)) 
    print("{:<25} {:<30} {:<10}\n".format(product, date, wrapped_info))
```

**Output:**

```
Product Name              Last Edited                    Information
ProductA                  2020-08-03 16:26:21            This painting was done by XNB.The artist
                                                         seeks to portray  the tragedies caused by
                                                         event XYZ. The painting weighs 2kg.

ProductB                  2020-08-03 16:26:21            This painting is done by ONN.This painting is
                                                         done by ONN.Decades later, it was discovered
                                                         in the black market of country XYZ.It was
                                                         bought for 2 million dollars by ABC.
```

Comment: Hi Deadshot, can I ask if there is a way to ensure that the display format will not be disoriented if Product Name exceeds wrap limit?